# Turning a transformer into an electromagnet

Tags: transformer, electromagnet

I saw in a YouTube [video](https://youtu.be/20_ZUx_iWuk) that people turned a transformer into an electromagnet by rearranging the T-shaped metal.

When I did the same and plugged it into the AC supply, it gets too hot. I tried applying 9V then 12V but it remains the same.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

From the video:

Transformer:

[image]

Modified for use as an electromagnet:

[image]

Comment: Use a supply that’s suitable for the job.

Comment: Akash, if you make and publish a video of what you are doing then I will watch the video you linked and your own video of your work. Otherwise, no dice. My crystal ball hasn't ever worked all that well.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that he turns on the "electromagnet" for very little time on the AC source. When you remove part of the magnetic path from the core and this path is not a complete path, the magnetizing inductance of the transformer (the coil inductance, in this case) drops too much and the excitation current shoots to very high values. That high current that is heating your "electromagnet transformer".

Note that in the video he inserts a rectifier bridge and starts feeding the coil with direct voltage.